# Check if a function is called inside another function

Tags: r, unit-testing

Let say I have the function

```
mean_wrapper <- function(x) {
  mean(x)
}
```

How can I check if the `mean` function is called?

An use case is for instance If I want to check this behavior in a unit test.

**EDIT:**

I make another exampe to be clearer. Let consider this function:

```
library(readr)
library(magrittr)

read_data <- function(file_name) {
  read_csv(file_name) %>%
    validate_data()
}
```

The aim of `read_data` is to read a CVS file and validate it. `validate_data` performs some checks on the data. It raises an error if one of them fail, otherwise returns the input object.

I want to test both functions but I don't want replicate the same tests I wrote for `validate_data` in the case of `read_data`. Anyway I have to check that the latter function has been called in `read_data`, so I wolud like to write a test that does this for me.

Comment: Check [this tutorial](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2010/08/17/unit-testing-in-r-the-bare-minimum/) to maybe get you started thinking about unit testing in R.  There is a package called `RUnit` for unit testing.

Comment: Actually I need a strategy to check the call in a unit test, in general I know how to perform unit test :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you need. Can you explain in more detail? Maybe crawl the expression tree returned by `body(mean_wrapper)` for an expression of more than two elements with `mean` as the first element?

Comment: I'll edit the question so that what I am asking should be clearer

Answer (score 2):

You could trace `mean`:

```
trace(mean, tracer = quote(message("mean was called")))
mean_wrapper(3)
#Tracing mean(x) on entry 
#mean was called
#[1] 3
untrace(mean)
#Untracing function "mean" in package "base"
```

Instead of a message you can use anything (e.g., assignment to a variable in the enclosing environment) as tracer.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I am checking if it works for me.

Comment: The approach works when I use `devtools::test()` but it doesn't when I use `devtools::check(document = FALSE)` or in the CI environment.